# PDDocSave takes more time in saving the files

Tags: c++, adobe-pdf-library

I found slowness in Inserting and saving the PDF files with the latest libraries (APDFL15.0.4PlusP4a and APDFL15.0.4PlusP2e). The slowness happens when the page count is more than 300.

The below code saves a 450 pages document using PDDocSave by inserting a temporary(accumulated) document with 40 pages each.

When replaced with an older version ( APDFL15.0.1PlusP1h) the performance was better.

```
  // Assemble accumulated files
  for(int j=1;j<=accumCount;j++)
  {
     sprintf(accumName,ACCUM_FILETEMPLATE, j);
     TSTBUG1(1,"Opening accumulator :%s",accumName);
     pdDoc2 = MyPDDocOpen(accumName);
     if (!pdDoc2)
     {
        SYS_ERR "Unable to open file %s \n",accumName);
        return PDFASSEMBLY_FAILURE;
     }
     PDDocInsertPages (pdDoc1,PDLastPage,pdDoc2, 0, PDAllPages,PDInsertAll, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
     TSTBUG1(1,"Inserting accumulator : %d\n",j);
     PDDocRelease(pdDoc2);
     PDDocClose(pdDoc2);
     unlink (accumName);
  }
  TSTBUG1(20,"Saving file =>%s<=",ptrMasterPDFDocumentList->ptrHeader->strOutputPDFFile);
  PDDocSave(pdDoc1,PDSaveFull|PDSaveLinearized,
           ASPathFromPlatformPath(ptrMasterPDFDocumentList->ptrHeader->strOutputPDFFile),
           ASGetDefaultFileSys(),NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: Have you contacted our Support (tech_support@datalogics.com) department? What you're describing sounds like a regression however it's difficult to comment on without having the document in question. You could try using the recently added PDInsertDoNotResolveInvalidStructureParentReferences flag and see if that helps. If not please contact us and we will immediately get started with a formal investigation.

Comment: Thanks Joseph.We have raised a query with Datalogics for this issue.